# Write data on post request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, post

I've attempted to do a post request with data to the streamlabs API, specifically retrieve a token (https://dev.streamlabs.com/reference#token-1), with the module "https" in Node.js, however I recieve a response telling me that the fields are wrong:

```
statusCode: 400
{
  error: 'invalid_request',
  error_description: 'The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the "grant_type" parameter.'
}
```

this is my code:

```
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const { SL_CODE, SL_CLIENTID, SL_CLIENTSECRET} = require('../config');

const optionsSL = {
    hostname: 'streamlabs.com',
    path: '/api/v1.0/token',
    method: 'POST',
};

var postData = querystring.stringify({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: SL_CLIENTID,
    client_secret: SL_CLIENTSECRET,
    code: SL_CODE,
});
postData = postData.concat('&redirect_uri=http://localhost/');

function testPOST(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{ 
        let req = https.request(optionsSL, res =>{
            console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            let rawData = '';
            res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk;});

            res.on('end', () => {
                try{
                    let parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
                    resolve(parsedData);
                }catch(e){
                    reject(e);
                }
            });
        });
        req.on('error', error => {
            reject(error);
        });
        req.write(postData);
        req.end();
    });
}
```

when I attempt to do this in CURL, I succesfully get a token even while copying and pasting the value of "postData", so that should not be the problem. Can someone please explain to me what am I missing?

--Edit
Here's the contents of the "outputData" of "req" after executing "req.write(postData)". `<client_id> <client_secret> <code>` are set to the actual values in the code

```
outputData: [
    {
      data: 'POST /api/v1.0/token HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 212\r\n' +
        'Host: streamlabs.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&code=<code>&redirect_uri=http://localhost/',
      encoding: undefined,
      callback: undefined
    }
  ]
```

Comment: try adding a content-type header (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: Like this? 

    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }

keeps throwing the same error

Comment: please show your curl cmd

Comment: This is it, obviously changing <client_id> <client_secret> <code> to the actual values:

curl --request POST "https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/token" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&code=<code>&redirect_uri=http://localhost/"

Comment: not sure if content length is computed automatically, try `headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
  }`

Comment: added, but keeps throwing the same, I edited the post so the contents of the data in variable "req" can be seen, maybe it could be useful

Comment: the thing is that querystring.stringify() doesn't properly encode characters like "/" or ":" which are needed for the uri, and since it just returns a string I figured that I could just concat it. I anyways tried encoding it with querystring, but keeps throwing the same error.